# S3 bucket doesn't work, It can't find the Bucket or the key

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I have the following code

```
    // 1) Define your bucket and item names
    bucket := "testBucket" 
    item := "test.json"

    sess, _ := session.NewSession(&aws.Config{
        Endpoint: aws.String("http://localhost:4566"),
        Region:   aws.String("us-west-2")},
    )

    downloader := s3manager.NewDownloader(sess)

    file, err := os.Create(item)
    numBytes, err := downloader.Download(file,
        &s3.GetObjectInput{
            Bucket: aws.String(bucket),
            Key:    aws.String(item),
        })

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Unable to download item %q, %v", item, err)
    }
```

I tested that I can list the buckets but the download fails because it don't find the bucket. Eventually I try to change the name of the bucket for testBucket/. So I have to put manually a / after the name of the name of the bucket to make it work.
With that I am able to list the files and see that test.json exist. But there is no way to  make the downloader find the file. I tried prefixes and suffixes like the / and ./ but it says that the specified key does not exist.

Comment: It looks the solution is already [here](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/go/example_code/s3/s3_download_object.go). Also see [s3_download_object.go](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/blob/main/go/example_code/s3/s3_download_object.go)